# Nested grouping in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, grouping

Is it possible to define few groups in one ListView? I mean group inside group, it is like tree.
If yes - any link to sample, tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) to define an individual item - This is typically used in a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) control